# Animation ( bar fills up over time ) with Jquery (Suggestion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I would like to replicate the same functionality as at `ign.com`, where the indicator bar fills up over time. I got it working but I got some sync issues after a while. So i'm open to suggestions to do it from scratch (I'm beginner with all this animation stuff).

This is the code.

```
function GoProgressBar() {

    var $lineStatus = $('.featured-articles-line-status');

    $lineStatus.css('width', '0px');
    $lineStatus.animate({ width: '694px' }, 12000, 'linear', GoProgressBar);

};

function GoOverlay(width, isLast, currentWidth) {

    var $overlayLine = $('.status-overlay');

    if (isLast) {

        $overlayLine.css('width', '0px');
        return;
    }

    if (currentWidth) {

        $overlayLine.css('width', currentWidth);
        $overlayLine.animate({ width: width }, 700);
    } else {

        $overlayLine.css('width', '0px');
        $overlayLine.animate({ width: width }, 700);

    }

};


function ShowNextElement() {

    var $elements = $('.element'),
        $overlayLine = $('.status-overlay'),
        $liElements = $('#elements li'),
        width;

    if (currentElement === elements[elements.length - 1]) {

        currentWidth = $overlayLine.width() + 'px',
        width = currentWidth + $($liElements[(elements.length - 1)]).outerWidth() + 'px';

        GoOverlay(width, true, currentWidth);


        currentElement = elements[0];

        $elements.hide();
        $(currentElement).fadeIn(1000);
        return;
    }


    i = elements.indexOf(currentElement) + 1;

    var currentTab = $liElements[(i - 1)],
        currentWidth = $overlayLine.width();

    if (currentWidth) {

        width = currentWidth + $(currentTab).outerWidth() + 'px';
        GoOverlay(width, false, currentWidth);

    } else {
        width = $(currentTab).outerWidth() + 'px';

        GoOverlay(width, false, false);
    }

    currentElement = elements[i];
    $elements.hide();
    $(currentElement).fadeIn(1000);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is a jquery progressbar() .. have you looked into this ? http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Thanks for your quickly answer, but I don't think the progressbar can help me dealing with what I want, have you check the ign one ?

Answer (score 2):

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

You could try this..

There are more features in addition to this,check it out.
Might come useful :)

Comment: Thanks, reading the API now, I will try to do some code just to test it

Comment: Sure no probs,do accept my answer if u are satisfied.
It helps me out too :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a wealth of ways in which you could do this.

You should have some kind of controller to manage the show and hide.

```
var Application = {
    show : function() {
        jQuery('.application-overlay').stop().animate({ top: 40 }, 500);
        jQuery('.cf-ribbon').stop().animate({height: 1000},500);
    },
    hide : function() {
        jQuery('.application-overlay').stop().animate({ top: -1200 }, 500);
        jQuery('.cf-ribbon').stop().animate({height: 200},500);
    }
};
```

Then you have your triggers : `Application.show();`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.cf-speakers .span2 a').hover(function() {
        jQuery('span',this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 },100);
    }, function() {
        jQuery('span',this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.0 },100);
    });;

    jQuery('.apply-now').click(function(e) {
        Application.show();

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery('body').click(function(e) {
        var application = jQuery('.application-overlay');
        if( application.has(e.target).length === 0) 
            Application.hide();
    });

    jQuery('.gallery a').click(function(e) {

        var src = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.main-container img').hide().attr('src', src).fadeIn('fast');

        jQuery('.gallery a').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
        });

        jQuery(this).addClass('active');

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Your css would of course come into play also but that can be left to you!

This should give you an example of what you need .. But you're already on the right track, sometimes there is merit in reusing other people code too you know! :)